# How to hide the html of my master page in the other pages of the site in online sharepoint?

Tags: office-365-developer

I have created a master page in online sharepoint and I have entered html code using sharepoint designer, the problem is that when I enter the other pages of the site, for example: '' Site settings '' all the html sections are displayed. I would like to know if you could help me understand if I'm entering the html code wrong or if I need to add something else.[image]The same thing happens when I click on '' quick edit ''

my question is, if this is the option to create master pages, will this error always happen?
or how I can edit a page layout and set it as default only to the home page of the site. I'm not interested in the content and the rest have the html. The only thing I need is that the main page shows the html well.

Comment: We can't help you unless you share the code of your master page. In general, it is not recommended to customize master pages in SharePoint Online. If you never did it before chances you will cause some unexpected issues that will keep coming up. You need to take into account pop-ups, full screen button, different types of pages, etc.

Comment: So what do I do in this case? I edit the html only in the webparts? or I can edit a page in the ''Edit page layouts'' in designer manager? 

Because I would like to know if editing a page here I can establish it as the main page.
The question is that I'm not interested in editing html in the web parts of the sharepoint since I have an html template ready.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the HTML container you've included to your master page has a class of .myTopMenu. If you don't have any classed - add one:

```
<div class="myTopMenu">
  <!-- scome content -->
</div>
```

In this case, add the follwing CSS to the place of your choice:

```
<style>

  .ms-fullscreenmode .myTopMenu{
    display:none !important
  }

</style>
```

**Explanation**

ms-fullscreenmode class is injected to the < body > tag when the the page is opened with the ?Minimized=TRUE URL agrument:

```
<body class='ms-fullscreenmode'>
  ...
    <div class="myTopMenu">
      <!-- scome content -->
    </div> 
  ...
</body>
```

[image]

When your page is opened in a normal mode there is no such class:

```
<body class=''>
  ...
    <div class="myTopMenu">
      <!-- scome content -->
    </div> 
  ...
</body>
```

**More details**

When we use modern UI to navigate to a SharePoint library or a list, we can click on the Qick Edit button. It will actually open a classic SharePoit page in an iframe with a ?Minimized=TRUE agrument in the URL:

[image]

You can test if your master page works correcty by experiemting with manually attaching ?Minimized=TRUE argument to the URL and seeing if it looks good.

You should also remember to include .ms-dialogHidden class to your new HTML code if you don't want it to be displayed in dialog boxes:

```
<div class="myTopMenu ms-dialogHidden">
  <!-- scome content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Tried this option but it really did not work for me. What I did was the following, I made a landing page and with the help of sharepoint designer I was able to show my css page and the issue is solved.

The following links help us understand how to create a master page and how to assign page designs to a master page:

Master pages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9MmWVOVDlU

Pages layouts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhzTHGkghDw

**Thanks for the help**